# Error in python using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to read different excel files, do some computations, add a new row for each file and finally concatenate those files. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from xlwings import Book, Range, Sheet
import xlrd
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date 
path =r'C:\\Dell\\SUB\\20'
import glob
list_dfs = []
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
list_dfs = []
for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_excel(f, ignore_index=True)

    column=df["TIME_ACTUAL_DEPART"]
    DT=df["TIMEPOINT_DWELL_1"].sum()
    DT_sec=DT*60
    exit =(df.iloc[-1,-1])  
    enter = (df.iloc[1,1]) 
    TT=datetime.combine (date.today(),exit)  - datetime.combine(date.today(), enter)
    TTT=(TT.total_seconds() / 60)
    TTT_sec=TTT*60
    df.loc[-1] = [ '','' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' ,'' , TTT_sec, '', '','' ,'' ,DT_sec]  # adding a row
    df.index = df.index -1  # shifting index



   dfs = pd.concat(list_dfs,axis=0)
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Dell\\SUB\\20\\output1.xlsx')
   dfs.to_excel(writer,'DWELL')
   writer.save()
```

and this is error comes after I run the "

```
df.sort_values(column, axis = 0, inplace = True)"
```

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
     in ()
    ----> 1 df.sort_values(column, axis = 0, inplace = True)
          2 
          3

```
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in sort_values(self, by, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position)
   3184 
   3185             by = by[0]
-> 3186             k = self.xs(by, axis=other_axis).values
   3187             if k.ndim == 2:
   3188 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   2021 
   2022         if axis == 1:
-> 2023             return self[key]
   2024 
   2025         self._consolidate_inplace()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1956         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   1957             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 1958             return self._getitem_array(key)
   1959         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   1960             return self._getitem_frame(key)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2000             return self.take(indexer, axis=0, convert=False)
   2001         else:
-> 2002             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2003             return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
   2004 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1229                 mask = check == -1
   1230                 if mask.any():
-> 1231                     raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
   1232 
   1233                 return _values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: '[datetime.time(22, 25, 59) datetime.time(22, 20, 33)\n datetime.time(22, 6, 47) datetime.time(22, 3, 53)\n datetime.time(22, 11, 35)] not in index'


         '[datetime.time(22, 25, 59) datetime.time(22, 20, 33)\n datetime.time(22, 6, 47) datetime.time(22, 3, 53)\n datetime.time(22, 11, 35)] not in index'
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace for your error. It's helpful to see which line is causing the error. Don't make people guess. Further, if you can show a sample of the data (df.head() for example) that also helps.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was eliminated by using only

```
column=("TIME_ACTUAL_DEPART")
```

because datetime data can not be indexed in python.

Answer (score 0):

The `.sort_values` method takes as an argument the *name* of the column, not the column itself. You tried to pass `df["TIME_ACTUAL_DEPART"]`, the actual column, as an argument.